# Issue in Weekend Holidays and Public Holidays in PHP

Tags: php, html, logic

I have searched the piece of code online. It's about getting the working days of the month (which subtracting the number of the Weekend Holidays (Sunday only) and the number of Public Holidays of the month).

Eg, my working days is from Monday to Saturday, but I have 3 public holidays in this month which are on 24th (Saturday), 25th (Sunday), and 26th (Mondy) of June.
Supposedly my working days will be 24. However, with this code,

```
{<?php 
function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays) {
    // do strtotime calculations just once
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
    //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
    //We add one to inlude both dates in the interval.
    $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;
    $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
    $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);
    //It will return 1 if it's Monday,.. ,7 for Sunday
    $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
    $the_last_day_of_week = date("N", $endDate);
    //---->The two can be equal in leap years when february has 29 days, the equal sign is added here
    //In the first case the whole interval is within a week, in the second case the interval falls in two weeks.
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
    }
    else {
        // (edit by Tokes to fix an edge case where the start day was a Sunday
        // and the end day was NOT a Saturday)
        // the day of the week for start is later than the day of the week for end
        if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
            // if the start date is a Sunday, then we definitely subtract 1 day
            $no_remaining_days--;
            if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
                // if the end date is a Saturday, then we subtract another day
                $no_remaining_days--;
            }
        }
        else {
            // the start date was a Saturday (or earlier), and the end date was (Mon..Fri)
            // so we skip an entire weekend and subtract 2 days
            $no_remaining_days -= 2;
        }
    }
    //The no. of business days is: (number of weeks between the two dates) * (5 working days) + the remainder
//---->february in none leap years gave a remainder of 0 but still calculated weekends between first and last day, this is one way to fix it
   $workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 6;
    if ($no_remaining_days > 0 )
    {
      $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
    }
    //We subtract the holidays
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);
        //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7)
            $workingDays--;
    }
    return $workingDays;
}
//Example:
$holidays=array("2017-06-25","2017-06-24","2017-06-26");
echo getWorkingDays("2017-06-01","2017-06-30",$holidays)
// => will return 7
?>}
```

I get an extra working day --> (24 + 1) days. I think the public holiday which falls on 24th June (Saturday) is counted as a working days, the program does not ignore it as a holiday.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to count Saturday as holiday or not?

Comment: Yes I do, for the public holiday (24th June), but remain working days for other Saturdays (3rd, 10th, and 17th of June).

Comment: change your holidays count condition to `//If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7 )`

Comment: Thanks man, can you post your answer below? I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip Saturday then simply remove it from holidays count condition

```
<?php
//If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend 
if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7 )
    $workingDays--;
```